# Pyro- Prefix in Chemistry

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

I was wondering is someone could please help answer this question for me. I was recently reading the ingredients on my toothpaste container, and one of the compounds in it was 'Sodium Pyrophosphate'; what does the 'Pyro-' prefix mean? I see it elsewhere but I've never come across such a nomenclature such as this. What does it mean in terms of Chemistry?

Answer (score 2):

It means that there are two phosphates connected together *under loss of water*, i.e.:

[image: pyrophosphate]

If you have any questions about the definitions of chemical nomenclature, have a look at the IUPAC gold book. See [here](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04959.html). It basically says, that a *pyro* compound is one that is formed by heating another compound, usually under the loss of simple molecules like $\mathrm{H_2O}$ or $\mathrm{CO_2}$.

Comment: So sodium pyrophosphate would be the sodium salt of the above acid ; )